# Disable The Suggested Meetings App in Outlook Web App

Tags: email, outlook, hotmail, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

My system is sending mails to my clients when they apply for position. Part of that mail is:

> We would like to invite you to take the next step

For Gmail users, it displays well, but in Outlook Web App my users see this sentence underlined and on click it shows suggested event.

Is there some escape character or some other way for me to disable this option? I want that sentence be plain text, not the event suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Outlook Web App that helps your recipients create events in their calendars easily. Could you please help us understand why is it a concern for your case?

More and more clients (especially on mobile devices) highlight meeting suggestions or meeting times and allow users to create events easily.

As a sender, you can't "disable" it. But the recipients can disable it via gear->manage integrations settings, if they do not like it.